# How to write SQLite code to show a specified code along with its associated codes from group_concat function?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, group-concat, having

I am trying to create a table where the code N09 is included, where a student was assigned a set of codes that contains N09, and "Status Complete" was yes. I wanted to use group_concat to see if each set contains N09. I saw a similar question to this but unfortunately, it did not satisfy my goal for Table 2 as it led to a problem. This problem I am experiencing is that it keeps showing 1 instead of 2, 3 for count. It also keeps showing N09, instead of N09 and its other codes from the set from the group_concat function. Is there a code to achieve my goal for Table 2 in SQLite? If my question is not clear, feel free to comment as I am new here.

Goal for Table 2:

| Student ID | Status Complete | Status Date | Status Time | Code | Count | Group_Concat(Code) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 03/03/2021 | 00:00:00 | N09 | 1 | N09 |
| 2 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 10:03:10 | N09 | 2 | N09, M33 |
| 3 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 01:00:10 | N09 | 3 | N09, Y03, B55 |

Problem:

| Student ID | Status Complete | Status Date | Status Time | Code | Count | Group_Concat(Code) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 03/03/2021 | 00:00:00 | N09 | 1 | N09 |
| 2 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 10:03:10 | N09 | 1 | N09 |
| 3 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 01:00:10 | N09 | 1 | N09 |

Sample Data:

| Student ID | Status Complete | Status Date | Status Time | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 03/03/2021 | 00:00:00 | N09 |
| 2 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 10:03:10 | N09 |
| 2 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 10:03:10 | M33 |
| 3 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 01:00:10 | N09 |
| 3 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 01:00:10 | Y03 |
| 3 | yes | 03/04/2021 | 01:00:10 | B55 |

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
select   Student_ID
        ,Status_Complete  
        ,Status_Date
        ,Status_TIME
        ,Code
        ,count(Code) /*over (partition by Student_ID,Code)*/ as 'Count'
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(Code)
from table1
where Code in ('N09') AND Status_Complete = 'yes'
group by Student_ID, Status_Date, Status_TIME, 'Count'
HAVING 'Count'> 0 
ORDER BY Student_ID;
```

Comment: Please share sample data that leads to these desired results. Without seeing the data from which these results were made, we can only guess. My best guess is that you should change `WHERE Code in ('N09')` to `WHERE Student_ID in (SELECT Student_ID FROM table1 WHERE Code = 'N09')`, but... that's just a guess.

Comment: Renaming (AS 'Count') happens last in the evaluation of the query so it is not known to group by and having. Beside, 'Count' is a string so it does not refer to your expression at all. If you insist on using identifiers that are reserved words, use "Count" to quote them. I guess your code should be: `group by Student_ID, Status_Date, Status_TIME HAVING COUNT(code) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `group by Student_ID` only since you want only 1 row for each student.
The columns `Status_Date` and `Status_TIME` of the results that you want seem to be the min values of each student (I assume that the dates have the proper format of `YYYY-mm-dd` which is the only valid date format for SQLite).
Also, the condition `Code = 'N09'` should be checked in the `HAVING` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT Student_ID, Status_Complete, 
       MIN(Status_Date) Status_Date, 
       TIME(MIN(Status_Date || ' ' || Status_TIME)) Status_TIME, 
       COUNT(*) count,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Code) Codes
FROM table1
WHERE Status_Complete = 'yes'
GROUP BY Student_ID
HAVING SUM(Code = 'N09') > 0
ORDER BY Student_ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5wbPgOug).

Never use single quotes for column names.
`'Count'` is a string literal when used in code. It never refers to a column alias.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This did work! I also have another question. What if I wanted to NOT include N09 (therefore wanting to delete the entire row in desired Table 2 that contains N09)? Would I do "HAVING SUM (Code<> 'N09') > 0? Or would it require more commands? Would it be easier if I were to update this post or write this post separately?

Comment: @mq19745422 `HAVING SUM(Code = 'N09') > 0` means that you want students that have `Code = 'N09'`. If you don't want students that have `Code = 'N09'` then the condition should be: `HAVING SUM(Code = 'N09') = 0`

Answer (score 2):

the WHERE cluase you have excludes all columns that are not N09 and have the status completed, so switch zu a `EXISTS` clause

As Lennart points out, here the having is redundant, as all rows now will have at least the count of 1

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
select   Student_ID
        ,Status_Complete  
        ,Status_Date
        ,Status_TIME
        ,Code
        ,count(Code) /*over (partition by Student_ID,Code)*/ as 'Count'
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(Code)
from table1 t1
where EXISTS( (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERR Code in ('N09') AND Status_Complete = 'yes' AND Student_ID = t1.Student_ID)
group by Student_ID, Status_Date, Status_TIME
ORDER BY Student_ID;
```

Comment: yes, that is true, but does this really matter besides that is is redundant

Comment: Just to clarify my previous remark: 'Count'>0 will compare the string Count with 0, not the variable